# How to reuse eclipse launch file in a new project

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, selenium

I just checked out an svn project in eclipse as a java project. There is are couple of run launch files in it that i want to reuse but dont know how to point 'Run' to see those launch files or use it. Any tip? thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually these are automatically picked up by the project and placed in the run menu. If they are not, Right click on the .launch file then choose 'Run As' and select the first option. This will run using that run configuration.

Comment: thanks a lot. what happened is when i imported the launch file into a new project, I didn't make the name of the project the same as the name associated with the launch files. That caused eclipse not to see them. Once i renamed the project, it worked like a charm.