# How to open a .launch file in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I have a `deploy.launch` file that I checked out with a project that does not include the Eclipse project in source control, it only includes the `.launch` files.

How can I add the existing `.launch` files to my Eclipse project without having to click "new external tools configuration" and then cut and paste the fields from the `.launch` file into the wizard to effectivly recreate the `.launch` file? I would much rather just, well, launch it.

Comment: Could be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674669/how-to-reuse-eclipse-launch-file-in-a-new-project

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just right click on the `.launch` file, select "Run As", and it's right there.

`.launch` files seem to get incorporated into the "External Tools" menu just by virtue of being present, although sometimes it decides it just won't bother.

Comment: from which wizzard, window, or view?

Comment: @Arthur: No wizard. Just right-click on the `.launch` file in the package explorer or navigator view.

Comment: I have the same question - assuming i've opened eclipse, and have a source tree in the file system with a .launch file (but no eclipse project) how should I open this? Not sure what package explorer or navigator view you mean in this context. Could you please explain in some detail? Much appreciated.

Comment: Launch files contain simply certain poperties like the class to run or the arguments of the Java runtime. So right clicking it (or importing them) just creates a run configuration using the stored arguments and properties. If the project is missing a launch configuration with errors is created and can be modified using the Run Configuration menu entry in the Run menu.

Answer (score 35):

File > Import... > Run/Debug > Launch Configurations

Comment: This answer was very helpful.

Comment: +1 The answers that mention right-clicking should mention that they are assuming that the launch config file is in your project explorer. This is not always the case.

Comment: when I tried this, Eclipse (4.11) *DELETED* the launch configuration files!  Luckily they were under source control and could easily restore them.

I'd like to know why Eclipse deletes files that you want to 'import'.

'Import' to me, feels like an operation that should not modify the source files in any way.  Copy sure, but modify or delete. NO.

Comment: yeah that just happened to me.

Comment: When I just tried this, it didn't import anything. It thinks it did because on second try it asked to overwrite ... but the imported configs just do not show anywhere. Oh Eclipse, why do you make common tasks so tedious. :/

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to `right-click > Run As` on the .launch file.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

Run-Icon-dropdown -> Organize Favorites -> Add

..opens a list with all .launch files associated with your project.
after adding, the files are available in the Run and Debug dropdowns.